# Specify border radius of UITextField in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I would like to programmatically specify the border radius of a `UITextField` using Swift.

By default, a `UITextField` has a slight border radius, however I would like to increase it and, after trawling through Interface Builder, I assume this can be done programmatically?

Comment: "corner radius" or "border width", which one? there's no border radius, just helping you clarify here.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

You can use:

```
nameOfTextField.layer.cornerRadius = 15.0
nameOfTextField.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
nameOfTextField.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
```

Comment: for later versions of swift `UIColor.red.cgColor`

Comment: did you see the result of your code? Corner borders are just cut off.

Answer (score 27):

If you're using Interface Builder, you can use User Defined Runtime Attributes for the controls you want to modify. At runtime, when the view loads, each attribute you pass a key path for will automatically be set to your value. No need to clutter up your code with little display tweaks.

The picture below should answer your question.

[image: Adding border radius with IB Runtime Attributes]

Comment: This is the best method since you don't let UI code living in the Controller.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Just curious, can we do the same for the following code: textFieldName.borderStyle = UITextField.BorderStyle.bezel ?

Comment: This has its limitation though. Sometimes You want to round things based on some other things.

Answer (score 15):

To Create a Corner Radius of Textfield below answer is correct:

**swift 3**

```
YourTextfieldName.layer.cornerRadius = YourTextfieldName.frame.size.height/2
YourTextfieldName.clipsToBounds = true
```

Comment: if you set layer's corner radius then why do you use `clipsToBounds` from `UIView` instead of `masksToBounds` of the same layer?

Answer (score 5):

in Swift 5

```
yourTxtField.layer.cornerRadius = 18
yourTxtField.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

Answer (score 4):

As @SnarfSnarf suggests you can programmatically tune the border widht and corner radius of the text field, _and any other view for the matter, by accessing its `layer` properties:

```
nameOfTextField.layer.cornerRadius = 4.0
nameOfTextField.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
```

On top of that, `UITextField` has a `borderStyle` property which you might want to play with. It has four possible values: `None`, `Line`, `Bezel`, and `RoundedRect`.

Finally have a read through [`UITextField`'s documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/tvos/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextField_Class/index.html), it's always a good way to find out all the possibility a class provides.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with a storyboard too. Just write this extension in your extension file. Then select the text field in the storyboard You will see the option to change the corner radius

```
extension UIView {

@IBInspectable var cornerRadius: CGFloat {
    get {
        return layer.cornerRadius
    }
    set {
        layer.cornerRadius = newValue
        layer.masksToBounds = newValue > 0
    }
}
```

}
[image]

Answer (score 1):

try this :`yourTxtField.layer.cornerRadius`
You can also find other methods here https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/tvos/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextField_Class/index.html

Answer (score 1):

This work for me,

```
  nameOfTextField.layer.cornerRadius = 15.0
  nameOfTextField.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
  nameOfTextField.layer.borderColor = UIColor.brown.cgColor  
  nameOfTextField.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

Answer (score 0):

To Create borderWidth of Textfield below answer is correct:

**swift 3**

```
YourTextfieldName!.layer.borderWidth = 1
YourTextfieldName!.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to add layer.masksToBound - I think the most popular answer missed that. You need the button to have the same form as its' borders. 
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer/1410896-maskstobounds

```
nameOfTextField.layer.cornerRadius = 15.0
nameOfTextField.layer.borderWidth = 0
nameOfTextField.layer.masksToBounds = true
```